# text-align: center; tag isn't working on an IOS device

Tags: html, css, ios, tags, center

Listed below is the code that I'm using to build a website. I've gotten this to display the way that I'd like it to on a computer (I'm currently using a Macbook), and when I scale it down and view it as it may look on a smartphone on my computer there are no issues. However, when I try to view one of the web pages on my iPhone 12 pro, the word "search" on the button on my search bar doesn't display properly. I'd like the word "search" to be centered in the middle of the button, but no matter what I try the word "search" remains on the right side of the button slightly cut off. I've tried the tag "text-align: center;" and a few other solutions that I've found on the web, but none of them work. I've made the search bar using javascript.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can get the word "search" to display in the middle of the search button?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0;" charset="utf-8">
    
<body style="background-color: white; font-family: sans-serif;">
    
<title>#</title>
      
<div class="page-wrap">
     
<div class="cp_cont">
<input id="cp_toggle03" type="checkbox"/>
<div class="cp_mobilebar">
<label for="cp_toggle03" class="cp_menuicon">
<span></span>
</label>
</div>
<label id="h-menu_black" class="cp_toggle03" for="cp_menuicon"></label>
<div id="body" class="noscroll"></div>
        
<header class="cp_offcm03">
        
<nav>
<ul style="text-align: center; margin-left: 210px; overflow: hidden;">
            
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">About Koizumi</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">Bibliography</a></li>
    
            
<div class="searchbar"> 
            
<form id="frmSearch" class="search2" method="get" action="default.html" style=" padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 20px; text-align: right; position: inline;"/>
<input class="search2" id="txtSearch" type="text" name="serach_bar" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" style="center: 396px; top: 185px; width: 180px; height: 26px;"/>
<input class="search1" type="submit" name="submition" value="Search" style=" padding-  
bottom:20px; left: 0px; top: 153px; height: 25px; width: 46px;"/>
<input class="search2" type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="default.html"/>    
    
    
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('frmSearch').onsubmit = function() {
 window.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=site:yoursitename.com ' + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
        return false;
    }
    
 document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').onchange = function() {
 if (document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').checked) {
 document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  } else {
 document.body.style.overflow = "";
  }
}  
 
if(!!window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type == 2)
{
    window.location.reload();
} 
    
</script>
         
</div> 
</ul>    
</nav>
</header>     
               
<div class="setsumei">
    
 <br><h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 40px;">◯◯◯◯</h1>
    <br><p style="text-align: justify; font-size: 16px;"></p>
    
 <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 13px;">Author: ◯◯◯◯</p>
 <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 13px;">Photos/Videos Taken：◯◯◯◯/◯◯/◯◯</p>
    
 <br><p style="text-align: justify; font-size: 16px;">    
    
    #
 </p>    
        
</div>
        
<br><div class="image">
    
  <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
 
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
    
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
 
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>

 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
    
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>

 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
    
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
    
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
    
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
    
</div>
    
<br><br><footer class="site-footer" style="font-size: 12px;">小泉© | <a href="#">日本語</a></footer>
      
</div>
</div>
      
<style>
    
 .searchbar{float: right;}
    
 .image{text-align: center;}
    
 .setsumei{margin-left: 20px;
           margin-right: 20px;}
    
 .footer{width: 100%; 
           height: 40px; 
           text-align: center;
           border-top: 1px solid black; 
           position: absolute;
           bottom: 0;
           padding: 10px;}
    
 .page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -40px; 
}

 .page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block; 
  }

 .site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
  height: 20px; 
}

 .site-footer {
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
        

 *, *:before, *:after {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}    

 ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
    
 .cp_cont {
    height: auto;
}
    
/* menu */
 .cp_offcm03 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
            transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
 .cp_offcm03 nav,
 .cp_offcm03 ul {
    height: 100%;
}

 .cp_offcm03 li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -6px;
}

 .cp_offcm03 a {
    display: block;    
    padding: 15px 45px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
            transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
}
    
 .cp_offcm03 a:hover {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

/* menu toggle */
 #cp_toggle03 {
    display: none;
}

 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_offcm03 {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
                    transform: translateX(0);
}

 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_container {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
                    transform: translateX(0);
}

 .cp_mobilebar {
    display: none;
    
}

/* content */
 .cp_container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    padding: 35px auto;
    -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
            transition: transform .3s ease-in;
}   

 .cp_content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 65vh;
    text-align: center;

}

@media (max-width: 1130px)and (min-width: 280px) {
/* menu */
 .cp_offcm03 {
        position: fixed;
        left: -250px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        width: 250px;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 40px;
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    
    
 .cp_offcm03 nav {
        background: white;
        border-right: 0.5px solid lightgray;
        margin-left: -210px;
    }
    
    
    
 .cp_offcm03 li {
        display: block;
        margin-right: 0;}

        
        
 .cp_offcm03 a {
        padding: 20px;
        
    }
    
/* menu toggle */
 .cp_mobilebar {
        display: block;
        z-index: 2000;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0 25px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: white;
        border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;
        
        
    }
    
 .cp_menuicon {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 25px;
        height: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
                transition: transform .3s ease-in;
    }
 .cp_menuicon > span {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 55%;
        margin-top: -0.3em;
        width: 100%;
        height: 0.2em;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background-color: black;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease;
                transition: transform .3s ease;
    }
 .cp_menuicon > span:before,
 .cp_menuicon > span:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background-color: black;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
                transition: transform .3s ease-in;
    }
    
 .cp_menuicon > span:before {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.6em);
                transform: translateY(-0.6em);
    }
 
 .cp_menuicon > span:after {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0.6em);
                transform: translateY(0.6em);
    }

 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar .cp_menuicon { 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
                transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    
 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar span:before,
 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar span:after {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
                transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    
 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_offcm03 {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
                transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    
 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_container {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(250px);
                transform: translateX(250px);
    }
    
 input:checked ~ #h-menu_black {
    display: block;/*カバーを表示*/
    opacity: .6;
}
    
 #h-menu_black {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .7s ease-in-out;
}
    
/* content */
 .cp_container {
        top: 60px;
        height: 92vh;
        text-align: center; 
    } 
    
 .noscroll{
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
    }
    
</style> 
      
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

first next time I would suggest you try to short down your code so that we can find the snippet of code easily :)

Anyway after reading the code try changing the style property `text-align` of the `form` tag to center instead of right.

```
<form id="frmSearch" class="search2" method="get" action="default.html" style=" padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 20px; text-align: center; position: inline;"/>
```

As I said, it is pretty difficult to guess something out of the whole page but try that...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried this, but unfortunately, it didn't work. Anything else that may help to center the word "search" inside of the button?